# Why are python keyboard module commands not executing?

Tags: python, while-loop, keyboard-events

I my python module keyboard commands are working fine as long as I don't have anything else in the infinite while loop.

As soon as I have something else in the while loop, the keyboard.is_pressed() does not work.

Can anyone explain why?

```
import keyboard
import time

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        print("/t/tThe 'a' key has been pressed")
        time.sleep(0.1)
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
        print("/t/tThe 'b' key has been pressed")
        time.sleep(0.1)
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        print("/t/tThe 'q' key has been pressed")
        break
    
    for k in range(0,11,1):
        print('k is at ' + str(k))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        
        
print('DONE')
```

Comment: I ran the same code and it is running. Can you specify what is the problem in your case?

Comment: Hi, yes, the problem is that the counter is running, but nothing happens when I press the 'a' or 'b' key...

Comment: Has anyone tried to run 'keyboard.play()' after using 'keyboard.record()' and with recorded keys stored? If so, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got it. The problem is that the `while loop` runs very fast. So to explain the problem the thing is that when in any iteration of while loop your if statements will be processed with very fast speed but in your `for` loop you are printing `10` values with `0.1` sleep time each and hence spending 1 second in the for a loop. So for you to get the result of pressing key 'a' you have to press it in the very very split second when your `for` loops end and while loop starts which is not possible and hence the only solution is that you remove the for loop.

Comment: Many thanks! This makes total sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`is_pressed()` returns true only if the key is depressed *right now*.

If you press and release the key at normal speed, it's unlikely that it will be depressed during the few milliseconds when `is_pressed()` is called.